# nanobind trampoline method name issue

Tags: python, c++, nanobind

I have a trampoline class that I am trying to wrap in nanobind like so:

```
class PyT : T {
public:
    NB_TRAMPOLINE(T, 1);

    void F()  override {
        NB_OVERRIDE(F);
    }
};

// ...

nb::class_<T, PyT>(m, "T")
.def(nb::init<>())
.def("f", &PyT::F)
```

It compiles fine, but when i go to use it in python, it only works if I call the function as `F()` despite wrapping it with the method name `f()`.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by using `NB_OVERRIDE_NAME` and specifying the name you want it to be overriding, so in this case it would be:

```
void F()  override {
    NB_OVERRIDE_NAME("f", F);
}
```

Comment: Why do you keep answering your own questions?

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa There's nothing wrong with answering your own questions. It's a good thing to do, in fact.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa Because I'm switching from Boost.Python and when I run into a bug I will probably forget how I solved, I make a Q/A for it, that and there isn't many helpful examples out there.